# Python imports wrong version of sqlite when running tests

Tags: python, windows, dll, sqlite, conda

I'm trying to set up a Windows slave for our Jenkins server, but some of the unit tests are failing due to a sqlite error.

We're using conda and have built a custom version of sqlite that includes rtree. Then our application is built using this custom sqlite. When we install our app on the windows server, the correct version of sqlite is installed:

```
$ conda list

sqlite                    3.16.2                    vc9_0  [vc9]  file://[package_server]
```

Running the app from the command line it works as expected. When we run tests though,

```
$ nosetests test

...

======================================================================
ERROR: test_vectorise_1 (test.system_test_wallet.test_rasters.test_vectorise.Test)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "farm\rasters\vectorise.py", line 189, in run_vectorise
    proc(progressfn)
  File "farm\process.py", line 1278, in __call__
    for feature in lyr:
  File "C:\bin\Miniconda2\envs\farm_system_test_windows\lib\site-packages\osgeo\
ogr.py", line 2876, in next
    feature = self.GetNextFeature()
  File "C:\bin\Miniconda2\envs\farm_system_test_windows\lib\site-packages\osgeo\
ogr.py", line 1460, in GetNextFeature
    return _ogr.Layer_GetNextFeature(self, *args)
RuntimeError: sqlite3_exec(CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE "rtree_GB_TEST_RP100_VE_5m_27700
_geom" USING rtree(id, minx, maxx, miny, maxy)) failed: no such module: rtree
```

I added some logging to show python executable path and sqlite3 path and it is the same every time, so it's not a virtualenv issue:

```
C:\bin\Miniconda2\envs\farm_system_test_windows\python.exe
C:\bin\Miniconda2\envs\farm_system_test_windows\lib\sqlite3\__init__.pyc
```

Printing the sqlite version though, shows some differences:

```
print('sql ver', sqlite3.sqlite_version_info)
```

Running the app from the command line, you get (3, 16, 2), which is the correct version. Running nosetests, you get (3, 8, 11) - an older version and presumably the reason for rtree not being found.

Weirdly, if you call a test file with

```
python path/to/test.py
```

and let unittest do its stuff, version (3, 16, 2) is initially imported, but then when the test runs, you get (3, 8, 11) and the test errors.

What is going on here? Why do I get a different version of sqlite depending on how I call the application?

I'm using python 2.7.14, conda 4.4.11 on Windows Server 2012 R2.

UPDATE:
I'm still getting this error on Jenkins and now on my dev machine too. It's not just a nose issue, as when I run the test using unittest, I get the error. The PYTHONPATH and sys.path are the same in both cases, and the call stack is identical, except with unittest, there are an extra two frames at the top.

```
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\envs\farm\lib\runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
"__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\envs\farm\lib\runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
exec code in run_globals
```

Interestingly, the rest of the call stack shows an absolute path for main.py, the entry point, and relative paths for everything else when using unittest. When calling main.py directly however, main.py has a relative path and all the other files have absolute paths.

Does anyone have any idea why we're seeing this difference? It's really frustrating having to skip a load of tests when we're running on windows.

Comment: Do you have an other python installed?

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi no, this is a new server and I have only installed miniconda.

Comment: The SQLite is just a single file of code, which is normally included in python and other programs. Could you check `nosetests`  executable. Maybe in windows they did some trick (sha-bang `#!/` doesn't work in windows). Maybe they included (compiled) a python version. Note: such test library is end-of-life.

Comment: I'm getting this error on my windows dev machine now as well. @unittest.skipIf(is_windows()) is a pretty poor workaround.

Comment: I wonder if unittest is importing it's own version of sqlite3 at some point so when you go to import your version it ignores the command. I had something similar and to fix it I had to delete the module del sys.modules["module_example"] and re-import it from the right place. Or you could try using `mock` to replace the calls to the sqlite in your code with calls to the correctly imported module.

Comment: This is all happening deep under the hood, so I'm not sure how I could re-import or mock anything. Both scenarios are importing from the same _sqlite3.pyd file and I think that is sometimes importing a different dependency for some reason.

Comment: I almost had it working by renaming `C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\DLLs\sqlite3.dll` to `sqlite3_old.dll`. For a while it was picking up the right version, but now it's gone back to the wrong version. I'm obviously going to have to find all the `sqlite3.dll`s on my machine and delete or rename them until there is only one left.

Comment: Still haven't found a solution to this and am relying on adding the line `copy C:\bin\sqlite3.dll %CONDA_PATH%\envs\%JOB_NAME%\DLLs\ /y` to the Jenkins build script.

Answer (score 0):

By looking for a solution in sys.path you are looking at the wrong place. You need to see what os.environ['PATH'] is at the critical points here since it's the Windows Loader that has picked the 'wrong' DLL, where by wrong I mean the first one it found according to its well documented DLL lookup procedure.

Comment: `PATH` can be different depending on the user, environment, and entry point. That's why we can't rely on it. Some applications (e.g. `nose`) like to insert entries into `PATH` so other locations are found first.