# Conda post-link script does not run

Tags: conda

Does anyone know how to get a post-link script to execute when using conda build? According to the [conda doc](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/build-packages/link-scripts.html), you can add a file called `.<name>-post-link.bat` to your recipe, but it does not tell you where to put it. I tried a few locations, and even though the build was successful, on installing the package, the script did not run. Maybe I have misunderstood what the post-link script does, but I got the impression it was supposed to run after the user installed your package.

The [bioconda docs](https://daler.github.io/bioconda-docs/guidelines.html#link-and-unlink-scripts-pre-and-post-install-hooks) state that `These scripts may be added at the same level as meta.yaml and build.sh`, but that did not work for me. I also tried the `<recipe_dir>\scripts` directory, but that did not work either.

The [conda build tests](https://github.com/conda/conda-build/tree/master/tests/test-recipes/metadata/_post_link_in_output) suggest explicitly naming your script in the `meta.yaml`, but that did not work either.

My script is very simple - it just copies a dll from one directory to another. It's actually a workaround for [Python imports wrong version of sqlite when running tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49158400/python-imports-wrong-version-of-sqlite-when-running-tests), so maybe I don't need a post-build script at all and there is a better way of doing it.

The command I'm trying to run is `copy %LIBRARY_BIN%\sqlite3.dll %BUILD_PREFIX%\DLLs /y`, so let me know if it is possible to get this to run as part of the install.

Comment: Sounds like this should be done in the `build.bat` script, no?

Comment: No, I tried copying the dll at build time, but %LIBRARY_BIN% did not yet contain the required dll. It must be installed to the env after `build.bat` runs.

Answer (score 1):

The post-link script worked for me on linux as follows:
Create a file called post-link.sh in the recipe folder (same level as meta.yaml) and build the recipe. The conda installation takes care of renaming the file to `.package-name-post-link.sh` and placing it in the right path so it gets executed after installation. In my case, ~/anaconda3/envs/env_name/bin.

Alternatively, you can also copy the file manually to the $PREFIX/bin as a part of the build.sh script.